# Why is there no text appearing on a dropdown when I typed a piece of code

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on **something** today, some kind of **dropdown** that shows types of languages a viewer wants to pick, I put the Languages: English, Francais, Deutsch, and Italiano. But for a reason these text langauges **are not** showing up. This is the code **I tried**:

```
<div class="language-picker js-language-picker"> <form action="" class="language-picker__form"> <label for="language-picker-select">Select your language</label> <select name="language-picker-select" id="language-picker-select"> <opt lang="de" value="deutsch">Deutsch</opt> <opt lang="en" value="english" selected>English</opt> <opt lang="fr" value="francais">Français</opt> <opt lang="it" value="italiano">Italiano</opt> <!-- other language options --> </select> </form> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `<opt>` tag to `<option>` tag

Comment: Really!? Okay thanks! **"Oh were did I got that code from?"**             Thanks! I tried that code and it works! but it seems like...Nothing!                                                                                                  **Keep Learning, More Coding**

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<option>` tags, not `<opt>`.

Comment: Really!? Okay thanks! **"Oh were did I got that code from?"**             Thanks! I tried that code and it works! but it seems like...Nothing!                                                                                                  **Keep Learning, More Coding**